# KeyError in Pandas when using ; as delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and unsure why this is happening. I'm attempting to import a small csv, separate the columns via ';', and then plot the close. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np
import csv

eur5m = pd.read_csv("eurusd-5m.csv", delimiter=';', parse_dates=['Date'])

eur5m = eur5m.sort_values(by="Date")

eur5m['Close'].plot(figsize=(16,12))
```

When I do this I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Close'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-5789795df4bb> in <module>()
      8 eur5m = eur5m.sort_values(by="Date")
      9 
---> 10 eur5m['Close'].plot(figsize=(16,12))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
_getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
_get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, 
item, fastpath)
   3841 
   3842             if not isna(item):
-> 3843                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3844             else:
   3845                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items)) 
[isna(self.items)]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Close'
```

This is a sample of what my CSV looks like.

```
Date; Time; Open; High; Low; Close; Volume
07/08/2018;20:15:00;1.16006;1.16012;1.15995;1.16;300
07/08/2018;20:20:00;1.16001;1.16023;1.16;1.16016;337
07/08/2018;20:25:00;1.16014;1.16023;1.16011;1.16012;225
07/08/2018;20:30:00;1.16012;1.16031;1.15997;1.16029;333
07/08/2018;20:35:00;1.16027;1.16095;1.16024;1.16082;509
```

When I sort by dates, it doesn't sort correctly. It seems to only work if I do eur5m.iloc[::-1]. Is this an indication of something?

Comment: The column isn't called `'Close'`, it's called `' Close'`. There's a space there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need problem is with traling whitespace, so possible solution is parameter `skipinitialspace=True`:

```
eur5m = pd.read_csv("eurusd-5m.csv", 
                    delimiter=';', 
                    parse_dates=['Date'], 
                    skipinitialspace=True)
```

Or [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with columns names:

```
eur5m.columns = eur5m.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! One more question if you don't mind:

When I use 

      eur5m.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

I get a similar KeyError, this time with Date. What's causing this?

Comment: @Phil I think best here is use `eur5m = pd.read_csv("eurusd-5m.csv", 
                    delimiter=';', 
                    parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'],
                    skipinitialspace=True)`

Comment: so it return `DatetimeIndex` from `read_csv`